# quotmark error message

Tags: errors, punctuation

Does anybody know why I get an error message when I use \tqt in \section{}?  How can the issue be rectified?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{quotmark}
\begin{document}
\tqt{asldfjlkasdj}
\section{\tqt{asdfas}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\section{\protect\tqt{asfas}}`

Comment: Do you know the `csquotes` package?

Comment: David's solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{quotmark}
\begin{document}
\tqt{asldfjlkasdj}
\section{\protect\tqt{asdfas}}
\end{document}
```

Fragile command in moving argument.